# JsonUnwrapped to deserialize GET request parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have the following:

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping
    MyDto test(@RequestBody MyDto myDto) {
        return myDto;
    }

    @GetMapping
    MyDto test2(MyDto myDto) {
        return myDto;
    }

    @Data
    static class MyDto {
        private String a;
        @JsonUnwrapped
        private MySecondDto secondDto;

        @Data
        static class MySecondDto {
            private String b;
        }
    }
}
```

However:

```
GET http://localhost:8080?a=a&b=b
```

returns

```
{
    "a": "a"
}
```

while

```
POST http://localhost:8080

{
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
}
```

returns

```
{
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
}
```

so it looks like `@JsonUnwrapped` and GET mapped Pojos don't work together as expexted.
Any hint on how to use complex nested Pojos to accomodate GET request params ?

Comment: JsonUnwrapped is an annotation in Jackson, so I guess it is not working when Spring converts query params to `MyDto` objects instead of deserializing request body in JSON.

Comment: @YangHanlin fair enough, but why it does during POST operation ?

Answer (score 0):

I may be late,
But spring uses jackson to deserialize the body,
while it converts query parameters directly

You can, however, use resolvers or converters to redefine the way your parameters are converted